# »Anwenden« vs. »adaptieren«

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice

> I am adapting to this tranquil environment.

Ich habe folgende Übersetzungsversuche des obigen Satzes:

1. > Ich wende mich in diese stille Umwelt an.
2. > Ich adaptiere mich in diese stille Umwelt.

Kann man *anwenden* und *adaptieren* austauschbar verwenden?

Comment: It's *adaptieren **an***, not *in*. *Anwenden* does not mean *to adapt* but *to apply*. A German word for *to adapt* is *anpassen*.

Comment: *Anwenden* is completely wrong here (*to apply*). Did you mean *anpassen*? The latter is more or less the same as *adaptieren*. But note that *adaptieren* is rather uncommon, except perhaps in certain (academic or technical) contexts.

Answer (score 10):

Beide Übersetzungen sind falsch. "anwenden" hat nichts mit Adaption zu tun. "adaptieren" ist ein (z.B. biologischer) Fachbegriff, der von Laien nie verwendet wird.

Für diesen Satz böten sich an

> Ich gewöhne mich an diese ruhige Umgebung. (Used if the adjustment is gradual and automatic.)
>
> Ich passe mich an diese ruhige Umgebung an. (Emphasizes that I'm consciously doing something to fit in, perhaps switching off my cell phone or something.)

Comment: You could add that "gewöhnen" = "getting used to" in your example.

Comment: Adaptieren an die Umgebung oder Situation ist ein wohlüblicher Ausdruck.

Answer (score 7):

*Adaptieren* bedeutet zwar *angleichen, anpassen, gleichsetzen, übernehmen*, aber es wird im Deutschen nicht sehr häufig verwendet. Ich habe im Rahmen des Informatikstudiums Leute davon sprechen hören, dass Software sich "an unterschiedliche Systeme adaptieren" können sollte, aber selbst dort klang es wie schlecht aus dem Englischen übernommen.

*Anwenden* bedeutet *to apply*. Das ergibt in dem Beispielsatz keinerlei Sinn.

> I am adapting to this tranquil environment.

Würde ich, je nach Kontext, übersetzen als:

> Ich passe mich an diese ruhige Umgebung an.
>   Ich stelle mich auf diese ruhige Umgebung ein.
>   Ich gewöhne mich an diese ruhige Umgebung.

Answer (score 3):

1. Nein, man kann »anwenden« und »adaptieren« nicht austauschen. Die beiden Wörter haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen.
2. Deine beiden Beispielsätze sind beide falsch.
3. Das Wort, das du suchst, ist »anpassen«.

---

### anwenden

anwenden = to use, to apply

- **etwas anwenden**

  > Musste die Polizei wirklich Gewalt anwenden?
  >   Did police really need to use force?
  >
  > In diesem Fall sollten Sie die ABC-Methode anwenden.
  >   In this case you should use the ABC-method.
  >
  > Wenn Sie den Filter ausbauen wollen, müssen Sie einen Bohrer anwenden.
  >   If you want to remove the filter, you must use a drill.
- **etwas auf etwas anwenden**

  > Sie könnten den Paragraph 5 auf diesen Sachverhalt anwenden.
  >   You can apply paragraph 5 to these facts.
  >
  > Ich versuche, mein Wissen auf diese Aufgabe anzuwenden.
  >   I try to apply my knowledge to this task.

---

### adaptieren

adaptieren = to adapt; but this word is rarely used. You more often use »anpassen« (see below).

- **etwas für etwas adaptieren**

  > Der Regisseur hat den Roman für die Bühne adaptiert.
  >   The director adapted the novel for the stage.
  >
  > Der Showmaster hat eine amerikanische Fernsehshow für das deutsche Fernsehen adaptiert.
  >   The showmaster has adapted an American TV show for German television.
- **sich adaptieren** (medizinischer Fachausdruck, nur im Zusammenhang mit Sinnesorganen wie Augen oder Ohren)

  > Das Auge adaptiert sich an die Dunkelheit.
  >   The eye adapts to the darkness.
- **einen Raum adaptieren** (österreichisches Deutsch) (einen Raum herrichten)

  > Beim Umzug ins neuen Gebäude mussten die neuen Büros erst adaptiert werden.
  >   When relocating to the new building, the new offices had to be prepared.

---

### anpassen

anpassen = to adopt, to adjust

- **etwas anpassen**

  > Der Schneider passt die Hose an.
  >   The tailor adjusts the pants.
- **etwas an etwas anpassen**

  > Du musst die Polsterung an die Form der Schale anpassen.
  >   You have to adjust the padding to the shape of the shell.
- **sich anpassen**

  > Walter passt sich an die neuen Gegebenheiten an.
  >   Walter adapts to the new circumstances.

  and finally:

  > Ich passe mich an diese ruhige Umgebung an.
  >   I am adapting to this tranquil environment.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way to express this is:

> Ich werde eins mit dieser ruhigen Umgebung.

meaning that you literally become part of the tranquil environment.

Once you finished the adaptation you could also say:

> Ich stehe im Einklang mit dieser ruhigen Umgebung.

But there is no way to use this construction (*im Einklang stehen*) to describe the process of adaptation.